# How to change the display view of the records and modified into a row

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have a SQL which can count the condition(Bad,Poor,Worse) in a day and group it into a month and displays as follows:

```
YEARS MONTHS LV    COUNTVAL
----- ------ ----- --------
 2009 Apr    Bad          5 
 2009 Apr    Poor         3 
 2009 Apr    Worse        2 
 2009 Aug    Bad          3 
 2009 Aug    Poor         2 
 2009 Aug    Worse        5 
 2009 Dec    Bad          5 
 2009 Dec    Poor         2 
 2009 Dec    Worse        3 
 2009 Feb    Bad          5 
 2009 Feb    Poor         3 
 2009 Feb    Worse        2 
 2009 Jan    Bad          3 
 2009 Jan    Poor         3 
 2009 Jan    Worse        4 
 2009 Jul    Bad          2 
 2009 Jul    Poor         3 
 2009 Jul    Worse        5 
 2009 Jun    Bad          1 
 2009 Jun    Poor         4 
 2009 Jun    Worse        5 
 2009 Mar    Bad          4 
 2009 Mar    Poor         4 
 2009 Mar    Worse        2 
 2009 May    Bad          3 
 2009 May    Poor         5 
 2009 May    Worse        2 
 2009 Nov    Bad          1 
 2009 Nov    Poor         5 
 2009 Nov    Worse        4 
 2009 Oct    Bad          5 
 2009 Oct    Poor         3 
 2009 Oct    Worse        2 
 2009 Sep    Bad          2 
 2009 Sep    Poor         4 
 2009 Sep    Worse        4 
 2010 Apr    Bad          6 
 2010 Apr    Poor         1 
 2010 Apr    Worse        3 
 2010 Aug    Bad          3 
 2010 Aug    Poor         2 
 2010 Aug    Worse        5 
 2010 Dec    Bad          4 
 2010 Dec    Poor         2 
 2010 Dec    Worse        4 
 2010 Feb    Bad          4 
 2010 Feb    Poor         3 
 2010 Feb    Worse        3 
 2010 Jan    Bad          6 
 2010 Jan    Poor         3 
 2010 Jan    Worse        1 
 2010 Jul    Bad          2 
 2010 Jul    Poor         4 
 2010 Jul    Worse        4 
 2010 Jun    Bad          4 
 2010 Jun    Poor         3 
 2010 Jun    Worse        3 
 2010 Mar    Bad          6 
 2010 Mar    Poor         1 
 2010 Mar    Worse        3 
 2010 May    Bad          4 
 2010 May    Worse        6 
 2010 Nov    Bad          5 
 2010 Nov    Poor         2 
 2010 Nov    Worse        3 
 2010 Oct    Bad          3 
 2010 Oct    Poor         3 
 2010 Oct    Worse        4 
 2010 Sep    Bad          3 
 2010 Sep    Poor         4 
 2010 Sep    Worse        3
```

The SQL that I am using:

```
select years, months, lv, countVal
from
(
select years, months, lv, count (lv) OVER (PARTITION BY years,months,lv) countVal  from

(
SELECT x.years, x.months, x.days, x.lv
FROM airtest, 
XMLTABLE ('$d/cdata/name' passing xmldoc as "d" 
   COLUMNS 
  years integer path 'year',
  months varchar(3) path 'month',
  days varchar(2) path 'day',
  lv varchar(5) path 'value'
  ) as X 
  group by x.years, x.months, x.days, x.lv
  order by x.years, x.months, x.days
)
)
group by years, months, lv, countVal
order by years,months
```

The problem for now is how to modify it to become in this format??

```
YEARS MONTHS   Bad    Poor     Worse
----- ------ ----- -------- --------
 2009 Apr        5        3        2 
 2009 Aug        3        2        5 
 2009 Dec        5        2        3 
 .........
 .........
```

After modified, It will become something like this.

You can see the seperated data are group into a row in each month.

Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conditionally sum into each column and group by year/month:

```
SELECT years, months,
       SUM(DECODE(lv, 'Bad',   countval, 0)) Bad,
       SUM(DECODE(lv, 'Poor',  countval, 0)) Poor,
       SUM(DECODE(lv, 'Worse', countval, 0)) Worse
FROM ( <your query> )
GROUP BY years, months
```

[Gaurav Soni added the following]

**OR**

```
WITH Base_Table AS 
( <your query> )
SELECT years, months,
       SUM(DECODE(lv, 'Bad',   countval, 0)) Bad,
       SUM(DECODE(lv, 'Poor',  countval, 0)) Poor,
       SUM(DECODE(lv, 'Worse', countval, 0)) Worse
FROM base_Table 
GROUP BY years, months
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it works not good. Values which after calculated becomes wrong and much larger. You can check it by this image: <img src="http://i.imgur.com/nZ3l4.png" width="224" height="399">

Comment: OK I get it...The method is delete the SUM() before DECODE() and it works perfectly. Thanks very much!!!

Comment: Well, that's strange. Without SUM() and GROUP BY you would have 3 rows for each year/month (5,0,0; 0,3,0; 0,0,2) instead of just one (5,3,2). Anyway, if your problem is solved then all is good :).

Comment: Yes, as you said, it will have 3 rows of each 'Bad', 'Poor' and 'Worse'. After I delete the SUM() function but not group by, it will display normally. The value will be a square of the original if I have not delete the SUM(). For(5,3,2) it will display (25,9,4). Anyway, Thanks again :)!!